# Hibernate CriteriaBuilder - How to match all elements with an equal field where the id is the same

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, h2

I'm trying to do something a little bit complicated with Hibernate 4.

I want to use the `CriteriaBuilder` to navigate a path. Here is the scenario

I receive a value from the user to match and a `TaskField` `uuid`. The values are nested in the following:
A Task Entity has:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "task", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
Collection<TaskFieldValue> taskFieldValues
... Other fields
```

A TaskFieldValue has:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "taskfielduuid", referencedColumnName = "uuid", nullable = false)
TaskField taskField

@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name = "TASK_FIELD_VALUE_PIECE")
@AttributeOverride(name="values",column=@Column(name="values", length = 2040))
@OrderColumn
List<String> values
... Other fields
```

And a TaskField has:

```
@Id
String uuid
```

So I want to search the Task database with the following criteria:
I want to get all Tasks back where they have a `taskField.uuid` value equal to that of what the user selected `(aka task->taskFieldValues->taskField.getUuid().equals(userChosenUuid))`

- AND -

I want only tasks to have a value that is contained within the collection of values within the `taskFieldValues` `(aka task->taskFieldValues.getValues().contains(value))`.

I want tasks that do not have 
Here is what (I thought) this predicate would look like:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder()
CriteriaQuery<Task> criteria = cb.createQuery(Task.class)
Root<Task> r = criteria.from(Task.class)
Predicate p = cb.and(cb.equal(r.get("taskField.uuid"), fieldName), cb.equal(r.get("taskFieldValues").get("values"), value))
```

However, that ended up in the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal attempt to dereference path source [null]
org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.path.AbstractPathImpl.illegalDereference(AbstractPathImpl.java:107)
org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.path.AbstractPathImpl.get(AbstractPathImpl.java:189)
javax.persistence.criteria.Path$get.call(Unknown Source)
```

Is there another method to be used in this scenario? What am I doing wrong? Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: can you add some more code

Comment: None of this seems to apply to Groovy, so I removed the tag

Comment: I am doing this all in groovy, hence why I put the tag (maybe it doesn't have any relation to the problem, but there is a lack of a semi-colon if you haven't noticed :) ). Ashish, I'm not quite sure what more relevant code there is. I added some of the hibernate mapping annotations and the creation of the CriteriaBuilder and Root<Task>. I hope that helps you help me.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind - I figured it out.

For anyone who else who has similar problems, this was my solution... I created a metamodel to make it a little easier to understand myself.

I had to join the collections and reference the individual fields by themselves:

```
def taskFieldValues = r.join(Task_.taskFieldValues)
Predicate sameTaskField =    cb.equal(taskFieldValues.get(TaskFieldValue_.taskField).get(TaskField_.uuid), fieldName)
Predicate taskFieldValuesContains = cb.equal(taskFieldValues.join(TaskFieldValue_.values).get("value"), value as char[])
ors.add(cb.and(sameTaskField, taskFieldValuesContains))
```